# Why should init parent class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have digging in the objective-c world. One thing that I can't understand is why is necessary  to call parent init method.
What purpose this ?

Answer (score 1):

same reason its necessary to call init on child classes
the init method wont be called unless its invoked
and parent classes have init methods that need invoking

as for specifics you would have to name a class NSobject, UIViewController, etc...
or look at the documentation and see if the init methods are listed

this is a slightly generic answer and id like to be more specific but IMO the question is asked "generically"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class and do some stuff in the init method, in case of it been inherited, you still want that stuff to happen, but now you are calling the child class init method. So unless you call the parent init the previews stuff will not happen.